# Asus TUF Gaming FX504 anti dust cooling is not working

Tags: asus, fan

I am using Asus TUF Gaming FX504 with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

This laptop has a anti-dust cooling fan that can be controlled through Fn + F5 key combination.

The problem is, the fan can only be turned on on Windows but not Ubuntu (the combination keys won't work on Ubuntu). I think it's may be because there is no available driver for that fan on Ubuntu system.

Is there anything i can do to turn this fan on on Ubuntu, thanks ?

Comment: See here for more research ideas: https://askubuntu.com/a/887070/459652 (You might want to rule out if you need the NVidia drivers for this model.)

Comment: did you manage to make it work?

Comment: No, I haven't. This model was designed to run on Windows 10 and it is a new model. I don't think there will be a driver soon on the ubuntu system.